# How to store values from NSMutableArray to string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, iphone

I am getting an NSMutableArray like this,

```
Selected Id : (
    2,
    92,
    154
)
```

It is not static, these value are added when I select multiple table view rows.

Currently I selected 3 rows whose id is printing in that array,
If I select one more row i.e 4 rows then array will be like this

```
Slected Id : (
    2,
    92,
    154,
    12
)
```

If I deselect any row, suppose I deselect 2 rows, then new array will be

```
Slected Id : (

    154,
    12
)
```

So that, I want to store these values in any objects which will be give me output like this,

```
154,12
```

i.e objects separated by comma

I selected 5 values then, it has to store like this

```
6,87,154,65,45
```

How to implement it ?

My Project Code :

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

         self.selectedPath = indexPath;

        if ([tableView isEditing]) {

            //  [selectedArray addObject:[_mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

            [selectedArray addObject:[[_mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"c_uid"]];

            count1=(int)[selectedArray count];
            NSLog(@"Selected count is :%i",count1);
            NSLog(@"Slected Id : %@",selectedArray);


        }else{

         /// other action
    }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.selectedPath = indexPath;


 //   [selectedArray removeObject:[_mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [selectedArray removeObject:[[_mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"c_uid"]];

    count1=(int)[selectedArray count];
    NSLog(@"Selected count is :%i",count1);
    NSLog(@"Slected Id : %@",selectedArray);



    if (!selectedArray.count) {
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Here I will get that selected data,

```
NSLog(@"Slected Id : %@",selectedArray);
```

Comment: you are currently getting array of selected id ? like `Slected Id : (154,12)`

Comment: yea right...! I want like 154,12  ...etc without brackets or any whitespace.

Comment: Can you paste your sample code.. How you are forming your array?

Comment: In your code didDeselectRowAtIndexPath will automatically call when you select next row then didDeselectRowAtIndexPath gives indexpath of previous selected row. so your previously selected row automatically remove.

Comment: All methods are working, what I want is that I want the id's in like 1,2,3 ...etc thats it.

Comment: @NikitaPatil then you should write only how to convert array to comma separated string so anyone will not be confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For do this you should take below `UITableView`'s delegate methods like,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
  //your code...      
 }
```

Now manage select and deselect row id by taking one mutable Array like below

```
var selectedRowArr = [String]() // Change if your id is Int or other type.
```

now you need to update above those delegate methods like below

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
     //your code...

     // First check "rowId" already added or not
     if selectedRowArr.contain(rowId){ // make sure "rowId" is same type of array 
        selectedRowArr = selectedRowArr.filter { $0 != rowId as! String } // remove object from array list
      }
      else {
          selectedRowArr.append(rowID)
      }
 }
```

Convert Array to string

```
let myString = selectedRowArr.joined(separator: ",")
```

> Output should be
>
> **1,12,13**

Updated :

First remove `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method I will edit your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

         self.selectedPath = indexPath;

        if ([tableView isEditing]) {

            First you need to check "c_uid" is already added in the Array or not ?
            if ([selectedArray containsObject:someObject]) {
              [selectedArray removeObject:[[_mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"c_uid"]];

                count1=(int)[selectedArray count];
              NSLog(@"Selected count is :%i",count1);
                 NSLog(@"Slected Id : %@",selectedArray);



                   if (!selectedArray.count) {
                     [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
                    }
            }
            else {
               [selectedArray addObject:[[_mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"c_uid"]];

               count1=(int)[selectedArray count];
               NSLog(@"Selected count is :%i",count1);
               NSLog(@"Slected Id : %@",selectedArray);
            }


        }else{

         /// other action
    }
```

If you want to convert array to string then

```
NSString * result = [selectedArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

> Output should be
>
> **1,12,13**

Comment: can u plz  convert your answer according to my code in Objective c, because I am not familiar with swift code.

Comment: NSString * result = [selectedArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]; this method works for me.

Comment: I know this was very basic question but, I was confused so I ask for help. Anyways, thank you so much @ipatel

Answer (score 0):

Hope will helpful to you following code!

```
NSMutableString *strProductId = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[strProductId setString:@""];
NSArray *arrTemp =  [selectedArray copy];
for (int i=0; i<[arrTemp count]; i++)
{
    if ([arrTemp count]-1 == i)
    {
        [strProductId appendFormat:@"%@",[arrTemp objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    else
    {
        [strProductId appendFormat:@"%@,",[arrTemp objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Selected Id : %@",strProductId);
```

> Output might be!
>
> **Selected Id : 6,87,154,65,45**